# What is the 6a[...] hash in OP_RETURN transactions?

Tags: op-return

I've been looking up OP_RETURN transactions on http://coinsecrets.org/ and I noticed that they all contain hashes that start with 6a, for instance:

6a28f7377a2065897e429287682bd2ed67ed7d0f5ebfc35cf4b1575756c3bebf0000b84002004b4d4400

Followed by their actual data:

[÷7z e~Bh+Òígí}^¿Ã\ô±WWVÃ¾¿¸@KMD](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/aa931bf51d5afcae1abe7db4ccc26095838f6439ccf5901a741a6dd0c8c9b32e#tx_messages)

Is that hash the encoded data?
If not, what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`6A` is the hex representation of `OP_RETURN`:  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script

That is not a hash at all, but rather the raw encumbrance script.  You are looking at the code that actually contains the `OP_RETURN`.  You can decode these scripts here:  https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/decodescript